# Removing gulp.src files after gulp.dest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, gulp, mv

I have a scenario where a client of mine wants to drop LESS files into a `src` directory (via FTP), and for them to be automatically outputted as CSS to a `build` directory. For each LESS file, once its resultant CSS file is created, it should be removed from the `src` directory. How can I do this with Gulp?

My current `gulpfile.js` is:

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var watch = require("gulp-watch");
var less = require("gulp-less");

watch({ glob: "./src/**/*.less" })
  .pipe(less())
  .pipe(gulp.dest("./build"));
```

This successfully detects new LESS files being dropped into the `src` directory and outputs CSS files into `build`. But it doesn't clean up the LESS files afterwards. :(

Answer (score 3):

Use `gulp-clean`.

It will clean your src directory once you piped it. Of course, test it on a backup with different settings, and if you can't manage to make it work properly, don't hesitate to make a second task and use some task dependency to run the clean after your less task is completed.

---

If I'm right, when I tried to pipe `gulp-clean` after the `gulp.dest`, something went wrong, so I got another way to do this, here's an example with task dependency.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    less = require('gulp-less'),
    clean = require('gulp-clean');

gulp.task('compile-less-cfg', function() {
    return gulp.src('your/less/directory/*.less')
               .pipe(less())
               .pipe('your/build/directory'));
});

gulp.task('remove-less', ['less'], function(){
    return gulp.src('your/less/directory)
               .pipe(clean());
});
```

That's for the not-watching task. Then, you should use a `watch` on the *.less files, but you should get task `remove-less` running instead of `less`. Why ? Because of task dependency.

When you'll call the `remove-less` task, it will only start once the `less` task is complete. That way, the files will only be deleted once your less compilation is over, and not in the middle of it throwing errors.

It may not be the perfect method to get this working as I'm not an expert, but it's a safe and working solution for you to use. Also it's pretty clear to understand IMO.

Comment: gulp-clean's Deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

`gulp-clean` is deprecated. Use the npm module `del`.

```
npm install --save-dev del
```

[Here](http://gulpjs.org/recipes/delete-files-folder.html) is how you should use it.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var del = require('del');

gulp.task('clean:mobile', function () {
  return del([
    'dist/report.csv',
    // here we use a globbing pattern to match everything inside the `mobile` folder
    'dist/mobile/**/*',
    // we don't want to clean this file though so we negate the pattern
    '!dist/mobile/deploy.json'
  ]);
});

gulp.task('default', ['clean:mobile']);
```